# ServiceStack ToJsv FromJsv missing some data

Tags: c#, debugging, serialization, servicestack

Using ToJsv (or ToJson) on a complex object appears to serialize correctly, but calling FromJsv does not return the original object with all properties.  Is there an easy way to debug the serialization/deserialization process to find the reason for the missing data?

`var complexObject = new ComplexObject(); <-- All properties have values
var serialized = complexObject.ToJsv();   <-- Appears to serialize all data
var deserialized = serialized.FromJsv<ComplexObject>();  <-- Some properties missing values`

Comment: You need to show the `ComplexObject` class definition + example data for anyone to have any chance to identify what the issue is.

Comment: There is too much proprietary code to show the ComplexObject class definition.  The real question here is, "Is there an easy way to debug the serialization/deserialization process"

Comment: ServiceStack.Text is dependency-free but some logging is available with `Tracer.Instance = new ConsoleTracer()`. But properties that are not publicly writable is not an error, it's your class saying do not set this property so it's just ignored.

Comment: Get-only auto-properties are only allowed to be set in the constructor.  Is it correct that i could call a custom constructor to create the dto using something like this?    base.RequestBinders.Add(typeof(ComplexObject), httpReq => ... requestDto);

Comment: That will let you take over the Request Binding and return a custom populated DTO for that Request DTO, but you're going to have issues trying to use DTOs/POCOs without writable fields and a default constructor which can't be used for deserialization or generic POCO utils like AutoMapping.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to my problem, but not a solution to the more general question of "how do you debug serialization/deserialization with ServiceStack?"

Resharper suggested: Auto-property can be made get-only.

Removing private setters from properties broke deserialization for ComplexObject.  Adding private setters to the properties allowed deserialization to work as expected (which makes sense).

Would still like to find a better way to debug problems like this.  I tried using JsConfig.ThrowOnDeserializationError, but I got nothing.  There must be a better way...